# Google Analytics events not save

Tags: jquery, google-analytics

I test with this code

```html
$(document).on('click', '.image-thumbnail', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      ga('send', 'event', {
        eventCategory: 'Imagen',
        eventAction: 'click',
        eventLabel: $(this).attr('src'),
        eventValue: $(this).closest('tr').data('product')
      });
    });
```

I don't have a error report in the console of my browser

[Google Events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjBay.png)

[Description error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFUbx.png)

Comment: check request status in browser dev tools network

Comment: I check the console, I see all white I Don't have error

Comment: Not the console...the network tab where you can inspect every request made in the page. If request status is 200 and data sent is what is expected then issue is in analytics console but might also not be sending correct data

Answer (score 0):

with your latest code will initiate the google analytics code on each click, that is not the best option.